# React how to expand spacing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, material-ui

I'm using Grid from `@material-ui` to display my data . Inside this Grid, I have multiple other grids, each represent a different section . I've use `container spacing` attribute of Grid, and gave it the max value possible (40) , but I need the spacing to be a litter bigger, and I can't figure how to do it..

```
  <Paper className={this.props.classes.root}>
  <Grid container spacing={40} >
    <Grid item sm={6}>
      ..
    </Grid>
    <Grid item sm={2}>
      ..
    </Grid>
    <Grid item sm={4}>
    ..
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  </Paper>
```

How can I expand the spacing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally `spacing` props add padding between the elements in the grid. so you can use the `className` or `inline` style to achieve padding between elements.

Sample code give below for inline style.

```
<Grid container >
    <Grid item sm={6} style={{padding:'30px'}}>
      ..
    </Grid>
    <Grid item sm={2} style={{padding:'30px'}}>
      ..
    </Grid>
    <Grid item sm={4} style={{padding:'30px'}}>
    ..
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. when I use this the spacing goes away entirely

Comment: @Yossi The padding should give to the child component not for parent component. I had edited my answer. Please check it out again.

Comment: Perfect .. thanks. (Note that I've used paddingRight instead of padding)